# Trying to move a div but getting "outerhtml is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, outerhtml

I'm moving lots of elements around a page, I have no access to the html so I'm doing it with javascript. Moving the innerhtml of a div is working fine, but if I want the whole div not just the inner contents I understand i probably want outerhtml. When I use this in my code however I get the console error "outerHTML is not a function".

Moves the inner html just fine:

```
function moveStuff () {
  idx('#IDX-description').after(idx('#IDX-field-extras').html()); 
  idx('#IDX-field-extras').remove();
  setTimeout(moveStuff, 1000);
}
```

Gets the console error:

```
function moveStuff () {
  idx('#IDX-description').after(idx('#IDX-field-extras').outerHTML()); 
  idx('#IDX-field-extras').remove();
  setTimeout(moveStuff, 1000);
}
```

Comment: `.outerhtml` is not correct usage, you need to use `.outerHTML` (Note the capitals). Javascript is a case sensitive language

Comment: There is not jquery function to get outerHTML of element. You should use simple js

Comment: it actually is capitalized in the stuff i'm using, still get the error. will update my question to be accurate.

Comment: @MaheerAli i thought this was using just javascript? on the site it's surrounded in a <script type="text/javascript"> tag

Comment: Try `outerHTML` instead of `outerHTML()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to convert jQuery objects to DOM elements you need to access it as an array:

```
idx('#IDX-description').after(idx('#IDX-field-extras')[0].outerHTML);
//                                                     ^
//                                                     |
//                note the conversion -----------------'
```

Also note that unlike jQuery's `.html()` the DOM API `.innerHTML` and `.outerHTML` are not functions, they're just attributes (actually [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set))

Comment: terrific! thanks so much, and thanks for the extra info about the differences between the attributes, i have a better idea what to google now -r

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
setTimeout(()=>{
  child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
},1000)
```

```html
<div >parent
  <div id="child">child</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move elements with methods like `.appendChild()` and `.insertBefore()`. The following demo has three `<section>`. Each `<section>` has an `<article>` nested within it. The objective is:

1. Move Article 3 to Section 2 as the last child with `.appendChild()`.
2. Move Article 1 to Section 2 as the first child with `.insertBefore()`.

```js
/*--Append Article 3 to Section 2---------------------*/

// Reference Article 3
var a3 = document.getElementById('a3');

// Reference Section 2
var s2 = document.getElementById('s2');

// Append Article 3 to Section 2 as the last child
s2.appendChild(a3);

/*--Insert Article 1 Before Article 2----------------*/

// Reference Article 1
var a1 = document.getElementById('a1');

// Reference Article 2
var a2 = document.getElementById('a2');

// Move Article 1 to Section 2 as the first child
s2.insertBefore(a1, a2)
```

```css
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

section {
  outline: 3px dashed #000;
  padding: 0 10px 10px;
}

article {
  outline: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<h1>Moving Tags</h1>
<section id='s1'>
  <h2>Section 1</h2>
  <article id='a1'>
    <h3>Article 1</h3>
    <p>Content</p>
  </article>
</section>
<section id='s2'>
  <h2>Section 2</h2>
  <article id='a2'>
    <h3>Article 2</h3>
    <p>Content</p>
  </article>
</section>
<section id='s3'>
  <h2>Section 3</h2>
  <article id='a3'>
    <h3>Article 3</h3>
    <p>Content</p>
  </article>
</section>
```